# Road movement by tanks in Memoir '44

Tags: memoir-44

In **Memoir '44** the rules specify that Tanks can move one extra hex (4 hexes instead of 3) if they remain on road hexes for their entire move.

My question is: What effect does this have on their ability to fire? Can tanks that remain on, and move only along, road hexes move 4 hexes and still fire, or are they limited to only 3 hexes of movement if they wish to fire? My son and I have been unable to resolve this from the rules.

For non-Memoir '44 players: For other units (ie infantry) the ability to fire after movement is determined by the extent of movement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Armor can move 4 hexes and still battle at full strength.**

From p. 5 of the [Terrain Pack rules](http://cdn1.daysofwonder.com/memoir44/en/img/mm_terrain_en.pdf):

> Armor may move 4 hexes on a road and still battle.

The [main rulebook](http://cdn1.daysofwonder.com/memoir44/en/img/mm_rules_part1_en.pdf) makes it clear that Armor's battle strength is unaffected by its movement (p. 9):

> [Armor] always combats at 3 dice.

P. 15-16 of the [FAQ](https://s3.amazonaws.com/dow-assets/www/M44_FAQ_v2_Lowres.pdf) has a concise summary of the effects of Roads on all units, which might be of interest if you have questions about other units.

> Armor - 4 hexes and battle